# Hue map of a RGB image in opencv

Tags: opencv

I want to check the hue map of an RGB image, so as to threshold it for color segmentation. Here below are my codes and results:

```
    Mat img = imread("circles.jpg");
    if(!img.empty())
    {
        namedWindow("Image");
        imshow("Image",img);

        Mat img_hsv(img.size(),CV_8UC3);
        cvtColor(img,img_hsv,COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        Mat hue(img_hsv.size(),CV_8UC1);
        Mat sat(img_hsv.size(),CV_8UC1);
        Mat val(img_hsv.size(),CV_8UC1);
        Mat out[] = {hue, sat, val};
        split(img_hsv,out);

        namedWindow("Hue");
        imshow("Hue",hue);

        waitKey();
    }
```

[image]

From the resulting hue map, I don't see why the top left red circle seems so bright while the lower red one is so dark? In this case, how to segment the red circles? The raw circle image is available at [circles.jpg](https://github.com/sol-prog/OpenCV-red-circle-detection/blob/master/images/circles.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an online [color picker](https://imagecolorpicker.com/), you can see that the upper circle has a hue around 350 and the lower circle has a hue of about 10 degrees. This happens because the red is at the boundaries of the hue circle:

[image]

If you want to segment the reds, you have to use two thresholds, since reds are both in the lower and the upper part of the hue spectrum.